# How can you retrieve the OpenLDAP password history list

Tags: ldap

I need to migrate the contents of an old OpenLDAP user tree to a new instance of OpenLDAP running on a different server.  The piece I am having trouble with is how to get the history of passwords which a user has used from their old OpenLDAP into their new OpenLDAP so that the new instance of OpenLDAP won't allow that user to reuse one of their 10 prior passwords from the old OpenLDAP.

I ran this command to get the pwdHistory:

- 'ldapsearch -b base -H ldaps://machine:636 -D cn=AdminAcct -W pwdHistory'
- pwdHistory:20210216200526Z{SSHA}e3kskc8tnsldktekalcilhiritnldingoilixdgf==
- pwdHistory:20210216636726Z{SSHA}9hge3hespbup9glxdgpigpih4t9skgnpiaigorpga==

I ran an ldapmodify specifying the pwdHistory parameter I wanted to updated and received a "Constraint violation" error.  This is due to pwdHistory being a read only attribute.

Anyone know of a way to get the pwdHistory values into the new OpenLDAP?

Comment: It is in the `pwdHistory` attribute if you're using the `ppolicy` overlay, but you may have trouble persuading the new server to set it: it's an operational attribute which only the server should set. But if this is a new server why do you care about prior password history?

Comment: A requirement in our system is that we don't reuse 10 prior passwords.  So passwords that a user used, which are stored in the pwdHistory of the old LDAP, cannot be reused even after we move to using the new LDAP.

Comment: Requirements are all very well but they aren't necessarily implementable ... and ' I can't seem to ...' is not a problem description.

Comment: Updated my problem description to be clearer - thank you for your comment.